# Regexp for matching executable version number

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression for matching executable version number.
It can be provided in two ways:

- `MAJOR.MINOR.TINY`
- `MAJOR.MINOR.TINY.BUILD_NUMBER`

I do not need to parse these values, just check for match. So, I can:
`^\d+[\.\d+]*$`. Ok, but this regexp will match strings with 5 and more version parts, i.e `1.2.3.4.5`. Also, it will match string like `1..2.3`. It would be great to do something like `^[as many digits as you want and only one .]{3,4}$`.

P.S. Of course, I can check for something like this `^(\d*)\.(\d*)\.(\d*)$` at first and the for `^(\d*)\.(\d*)\.(\d*)\.(\d*)$` if not matched. But maybe there is a better (smarter) way to do this.

I use `re` python module for checking the match:

```
import re

version_regexp = re.compile(r'^\d+[\.\d+]*$')
versions = ['dsvfsdf',
            '1.a.3',
            '1.2.4',
            '1.4..5.6',
            '0.3.1',
            'a.b.c.d',
            '1,2,3']
for i, sample in enumerate(versions):
    print('Sample[%d]: %s' % (i, True if version_regexp.match(sample) else False))
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The regex should be like `re.compile(r'^\d+(\.\d+){2,3}$')`

Comment: D'ouh, realy simple. Thanks!